# Prove uniqueness of a certain arrow in the $\mathbf{Pno}$ category

Tags: category-theory

This question is based on the exercise 1.2.1 from Harold Simmons book, *An Introduction to Category Theory*.

Consider the category $\textbf{Pno}$ whose objects are $(A,\alpha,a)$, where $A$ is a set, $\alpha:A\rightarrow A$ is a function and $a\in A$ is a distinguished element. The arrows of $\mathbf{Pno}$ are $f:(A,\alpha,a)\rightarrow(B,\beta,b)$, where $f\circ\alpha = \beta\circ f$ and $f(a)=b$.

They asked to prove that there is a unique arrow $f:(\mathbb{N},succ,0)\rightarrow (A,\alpha,a)$, for every object $(A,\alpha,a)$ of $\mathbf{Pno}$, where $succ$ is the successor function.

This arrow is given by $f(n)=\alpha^n(a)$, which verify the properties to be a $\mathbf{Pno}$-arrow. Now, in the solution section they say that a proof by induction proves that this is the only arrow. However, I don't see how an induction (I guess this induction must be done over $n$) proves the uniqueness of this arrow.

Could anybody give me a hand with this? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g : (\mathbb N, s,0) \to (A,\alpha, a)$ be an arrow. $g(0) = a = \alpha^0(a)$ holds by assumption. Suppose $g(n) = \alpha ^n(a)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $g(n+1) = gs(n) = \alpha g(n) = \alpha (\alpha ^n(a)) = \alpha ^{n+1}(a)$. So we have an initial object in the category.

Comment: What do you mean by "we have an initial object in the category"?

Comment: @JaviLark01 The object $(\mathbb N, s, 0)$ is an initial object of $\mathbf{Pno}$

Comment: Hmm... Ok. However, I don't see how this proves the uniqueness. Sorry for my clumsiness. I'm pretty new in this subject.

Comment: @JaviLark01 Morphisms $(\mathbb N, s, 0) \to (A,\alpha, a)$ exist. Any two such morphisms must be equal. Hence, the morphism is unique.

Comment: Ok, now I see. My apologies and thank you very much!!